# python cytpes creating callback function - Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: python, c++, ctypes

i'm trying to create a python bind for the [Ultralight](https://github.com/ultralight-ux/Ultralight) project.

But I got stuck when creating a bind for the callback function that is defined as the follow:

```cpp
typedef JSValueRef 
(*JSObjectCallAsFunctionCallback) (JSContextRef ctx, JSObjectRef function, JSObjectRef thisObject, size_t argumentCount, const JSValueRef arguments[], JSValueRef* exception);
```

Im tring to bind it like this:

```py
JS_OBJECT_CALL_AS_FUNCTION_CALLBACK = ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(
    ctypes.c_void_p,  # return JSValueRef *JSObjectCallAsFunctionCallback)
    ctypes.c_void_p,  # param JSContextRef ctx
    ctypes.c_void_p,  # param JSObjectRef function
    ctypes.c_void_p,  # param JSObjectRef thisObject
    ctypes.c_size_t,   # param size_t argumentCount
    ctypes.c_void_p,  # param const JSValueRef arguments[]
    ctypes.c_void_p,  # param JSValueRef* exception
)

def GetMessage(
    ctx, function, thisObject, argumentCount, arguments, js_exception
) -> ctypes.c_void_p:
    print("Hello World!")
    #...
    #return ctypes.c_void_p

js_object_call_as_function_callback = JS_OBJECT_CALL_AS_FUNCTION_CALLBACK(GetMessage)
```

But when I tried to use `js_object_call_as_function_callback` sending it to another function (which is called `JSObjectMakeFunctionWithCallback`) I got a `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` error.

```cpp
JS_EXPORT JSObjectRef JSObjectMakeFunctionWithCallback(JSContextRef ctx, JSStringRef name, JSObjectCallAsFunctionCallback callAsFunction);
```

I already have a working `JSContextRef` and `JSStringRef` but the callback function isn't working.

Is it possible to create that callback? And if so, how can I do it?

Comment: Assuming `c_void_p` is appropriate for whatever `JSXxxxRef`s are, the `size_t` should be a `ctypes.c_size_t`.  `c_ulong` might not be correct depending on your CPU and OS.

Comment: oh, that's correct. I didn't realize that `cytpes` got a `c_size_t` property... I made the correction but the error continue to occur.
IDK, I never worked with callbacks function that have a return different from `void` on `ctypes`. Do you think that it's alright to use `ctypes.c_void_p` as return value?
My OS information:
`Linux version 4.15.0-109-generic (buildd@lgw01-amd64-010) (gcc version 7.5.0 (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04)) #110-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jun 23 02:39:32 UTC 2020`